# iPhone can't dial to <a href="dial: *number">*number</a>

Tags: iphone, href, tel

iPhone can't dial to `<a href="tel:*number">*number</a>` on HTML page.

Press on this link ask you to call bet never dial, can dial only without the `*`.

On Android it's work O.K.

Comment: Dial what? Please share your html code. The url scheme for iPhone is `tel:` not `dial:` are you using `tel:`?

Comment: this is my html: <a href="tel:*5051">*5051</a>

Comment: So why have you said `dial:` if you are using `tel:` already? Your question was very misleading because you didn't give us the correct code. Remove the `*` there is no reason for the `*` at all.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I am using tel:, the * is part of the phone number and this is the problem.

Comment: `*` alone is not valid for the number so it will not work. You could have a look at encoding but not sure that will help either. Why do you need a `*`?

Comment: Thank you, We have customers using * prefix for phone numbers

Comment: I was about to update my answer with an objective-c answer but obviously you don't want that, silly me. What you could try doing is encoding the telephone number before setting the href so that the * is escaped. Not sure if this will work or not but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [Apple documentation for URL Scheme's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH6-SW1)

Notice that to get an iphone to dial out from html you need to use `tel:` not `dial:` So your html should look like

```
<a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>
```